# How to simplify and reset props from parent to child components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-class-components

I am trying to reset data passed as props to children components. How should i write this ?

Context: i'm converting a ThreeJS implementation into Vue/Typescript. It includes a controls panel composed with slider inputs controlling parameters of the Three canvas.
I separated this massive monolithic original code into 3 components :
- child1: the controlsPanel, contains sliders and the reset button
- child2: the Vue-GL canvas, emitting mouse events
- parent: the component hosting initial data, and reseting.

parent :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child1 :prop1="prop1" :prop2="prop2" :child1Prop="child1Prop" :reset="reset" />
    <child2 :prop1="prop1" :prop2="prop2" :child2Prop="child2Prop" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  import Child1 from './components/Child1.vue';
  import Child2 from './components/Child2.vue';

  const initialState = {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    child1Prop: 'some text',
    child2Prop: 'another text',
  }
  export type InitialState = typeof initialState;

  @Component({
    components: {
      Child1,
      Child2,
    },
  })
  export default class App extends Vue {
    public prop1!: InitialState['prop1'];
    public prop2!: InitialState['prop2'];
    public child1Prop!: InitialState['child1Prop'];
    public child2Prop!: InitialState['child2Prop'];

    public beforeMount() {
      Object.assign(this, initialState);
    }

    public reset() {
      Object.assign(this, initialState);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child code :

```
<template>
...
<!-- this button is only in Child1 -->
<button type="button" @click="resetCamera">Reset</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  // import VueAsyncComputed, { IAsyncComputedProperty } from 'vue-async-computed';
  import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import { InitialState } from '../App.vue';

  @Component
  export default class ChildX extends Vue {
    @Prop() public prop1!: InitialState['prop1'];
    @Prop() public prop2!: InitialState['prop2'];
    @Prop() public childXProp!: InitialState['childXProp']; // Specific prop

    // computed getters and methods using this.prop1 etc...

    // this method is only in Child1
    public resetCamera() {
      this.reset();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Properties prop1 and prop2 are controlled by Child1 component and consumed by Child2. Child2 can also update these props (via mouse events), which should update sliders in Child1 appropriately.

I managed to make Typescript happy, but at the cost of typings everywhere...

Question1: is there a way to simplify while keeping the 2way-bindings between childs and parent App ? (2way-bindings don't work with above code)

Question2: How to reset all props ? my child1.resetCamera seems to call parent reset() but props are not reseting ...

Comment: Props aren't supposed to be two-way binding. Their main purpose is "pass this object from parent to child", that's it. Changing props in children may create problems because it may be hard to know what's changing your data: parent or child? My suggestion: use props as "current data", so when you reset them, it'll be simply done by changing the props, once it'll reflect on the children components. Instead of changing the props inside the children components, emit events and catch them in the parent and then decide what to do (change props, maybe).

Comment: thanks, your suggestions pointed my thoughts towards v-model :
i implemented a single v-model object containing common props for both children, and put it in both children props.
Result https://github.com/Sharlaan/webgl-area-picking-vue

It works partially in the sense that updating with mouse from the webgl container does not update the sliders. Working on reset now, with your suggestion.

Comment: That's great. I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `props`, you should be careful about the point of this kind of data: its main purpose is simply to pass data from parent to child, that is it.

As you might figure that out later, usually it is not a good idea to change `props` both in parent and child. Why? Consider the following example:

A parent component called `mainComponent` passes `currentID` to all its children: `headerComponent` and `footerComponent`. However, if you have designed your `props` to be changed by both parent and children, if `footerComponent` changes `currentID` it also changes in `headerComponent` which may not be expected. How about a third child component being added to your parent component that uses `currentID` as well? It will be affected too.

Using the above example, my suggestion is: use `props` in only one-way binding. In other words, `mainComponent` passes `currentID` to all its children. If any of these needs to change that `props`, emit an event by using `$emit("updateCurrentID", newCurrentID)` and catching this up in the `mainComponent` and, finally, change `currentID` and that will reflect on all children. But now, you are sure you are updating this `props` data in only one place (`mainComponent`).

To emit that, I can think of two possibilities: by `$emit` itself ([docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)) or by creating your own custom events, as you can see [here - a tutorial by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Hope it helps

Comment: The behavior description you wrote is actually exactly what i'm expecting :
if one component (be it one of children or the parent) changes a property, its new value must be reflected everywhere.

At exception of the reset method, there yes i want only the parent to handle that, so i put in child.button.@click="$emit('reset')" which effectively calls the parent's reset method and trigger its logic.

Comment: Exactly. You got the idea. When you change `props` in a lot of places, trust me, it becomes a mess.